# How to implement a table that appears / expands when the "expand" button is clicked?

Tags: silverlight

Is it better to build 2 different pages? Such that when a button is clicked, it leads to another page with the table? Or can we hide the table until the "expand" button is clicked? Is it better to present the table as a listbox?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would'nt do it with two seperate pages.
You can use a simple expander and style it for your purpose. Here's a video how to use the expander: http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-toolkit-creating-a-toolkit-expander/ and here's a simple tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/768/.

You could also use a simple toggle button and bind the visibility of the table (DataGrid or ListBox, whatever you want) with a converter to the checked state of the toggle button. Somehow like this:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="myToggleButton" />
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding ElementName, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}}"/>
```

The BoolToVisibleConverter is a class which implements IValueConverter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

I don't know your exact aim, but I guess the expander approach is good for you.

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Comment: Thanks, Terrance. The video is great, exactly what I need. it seems like I need to add System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit as a reference, but I can not locate anywhere in the SDK folder, would you have any idea where i can find it? Thanks. Ive got Visual Studio 2010 and Silverlight 4.0 SDK installed :)

Comment: Thanks, seems like I didnt install the toolkit, should solve the problem once it is installed :)

Comment: You can download the silverlight toolkit here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/. Then it should appear in vs2010 as reference. If not you can find it normally here: C:\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Bin.
P.S. Mark as answer if this is solves your problem ;)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. emmm.. i was going to implement the table as a list-box, then thought, maybe Data-grid may not be a bad idea either. Would you possibly have some insights on this? All I wanted to do it to have some data stored in a table, such that when the "expand" button is pressed, the table shows :) Thanks

Comment: The datagrid supports some build in functionality like sorting. If you use a PagedCollectionView as ItemSource you can extend the functionality to grouping and sorting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072(v=vs.95).aspx). It depends on what you want and how the data is "designed". If you want to display only one property in the list and you don't want sorting, grouping,... you should use a ListBox. If you want to display more than one property in the ListBox you need to define an items template, which means fix sizes of the single elements. If you use a datagrid

Comment: the sizes are more flexible. The datagrid is of course more powerful. Both are virtualizing by default, so I would use a data grid if you want to display more than one property and if you want to do some sorting, filtering, ...

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. i will use a DataGrid then. Am I able to add buttons in datagrid? Can i have each of the properties stored in an array (not just a string), and display them on multiple lines? Hope Im making sense..

Comment: In a DataGrid you can set the AutoGenerateColumns Property to false, then you can define your own Column templates. Then you can use a TemplatedColumn(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.95).aspx) where you can put in a Button or whatever you want ;). If you just want to display Text you can use the DataGridTextColumn.(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/03/27/defining-columns-for-a-silverlight-datagrid.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think a converter is the way to go, like TerrenceJackson said!

In the DataGrid your Binding should look like this:

```
<CheckBox Content="Expand" Height="72" Name=MyExpandCheckbox IsChecked="False" />
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyExpandCheckbox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}}"/>
```

You have to set the Name of your Button/Checkbox/... for the ElementName in the binding for the visibility-property.

Here is an example of a BoolToVisibilityConverter:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter member

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Boolean)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```